# Why is "Connect to Server" bookmarking gone in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

I was previously using 10.10, and I loved the bookmarking feature of "Connect to Server". Why was that removed? or is it somewhere else that i'm not looking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I have already established a connection using the Connect to Server, and it appears in the side panel of Nautilus under the Network heading, the option of "Add Bookmark" appears for me if I right click on my connected share. When I click and Add Bookmark, it does add a bookmark for the connection under the bookmark section for me, Hope this helps...

Here are screen shots of what it will look like when you right click on a connection, and add a bookmark.

[image: Screenshot of adding the bookmark]

---

[image: Screenshot of bookmark once added]

Comment: I'm really glad it helped you!

Comment: Seems like they made it harder to find the connect to server tool and bookmarking your connections

Comment: It used to be left-click Places and left-click connect to.. Now, you can right-click the home button and left-click connect to. Just need to add it. During a spring clean, you often move things around.

Comment: A screenshot here would be really awesome.

Comment: Will add one...